# How to handle HorizontalScrollView's input inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview, nestedscrollview, coordinator-layout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout`, inside of it:  `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (`ImageView` and `toolbar`), and `NestedScrollView`.

Inside `NestedScrollView` I have `HorizontalScrollView`. When I horizontally scroll the `HorizontallScrollView` my `NestedScrollView` catches the input as vertical scroll and only once on four times the horizontal scroll works fine. How can I resolve it?
I've got no problems with normal `ScrollView`.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

        >

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/test_primi"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

            />

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

            >

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_titolo_toolbar_primi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

                >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="backToRicette"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_freccia_back_bianca"

                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:text="Primi"
                    android:textColor="@color/titoliToolbar"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimensioneTitoliToolbar"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_titolo_toolbar_primi"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_layout_bordi_radius"
                android:elevation="2dp"

                >

                <ImageView

                    android:id="@+id/icona_search_action_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_96"

                    />

                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_cerca_ricette"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:hint="Cerca"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/corpoText"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hintText"
                    android:textSize="20dp"

                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view_ricette_primi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    >



     <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/body"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_ricette_top_10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_layout_bordi_radius"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/text_view_top_10_ricette"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Top 10 Primi"
                    android:textColor="@color/titoli"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimensioneTitoli"

                    />

                <HorizontalScrollView

                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view_top_10_ricette"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none"

                    >

                    <!-- Here is an horizontal linear layout with 10 images. -->

                  </HorizontalScrollView>

               </LinearLayout>

           </LinearLayout>

      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: Will you please share your xml?